# synchronized span for block by synchronized method return value

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I have a synchronized method like below:

```
static Object foo (Map m, String key) {
  synchronized (m) {
    //...
    return m.get(key);
  }
}
```

and another method that calls this method:

```
static void bar (Map m, Stirng key) {
  synchronized (foo (m,key) ) {
    //Is m still synchronized locked here?
    //...
  }
}
```

My question is as above. Since the synchronized block is on the return value of foo, I want to know the answer on these questions:

- only m synchronized?
- only m.get(key) synchronized?
- both m and m.get(key) synchronized?

Comment: Once you're in the `synchronized` block for `bar`, the lock on `m` has been released, and the thread only holds the lock for the result of `foo`.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case,

```
synchronized (foo (m,key) ) {
  /* Critical section. */
}
```

… in the critical section, the thread only holds a lock on the result of `m.get(key)` The thread did acquire the lock on `m`, but it was released before returning from `foo()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any reference I can take a look on this?

Comment: @texasbruce [JLS, Section 14.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19).

Comment: I'd recommend Java Concurrency in Practice. I'm currently reading it, and it's been great so far. It covers basic synchronization early on, then delves deeper into other topics.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix I will get the book and read it. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: The reference explained it. Thanks!

Comment: @texasbruce _is there any reference..._  Well, that would be the Java Language Spec, but it's really pretty simple:  `synchronized(` _exp_ `) {...}` first evaluates the expression _exp_, then it acquires the lock for the object that is referenced by the result of that evaluation, then it performs the `...`, and then it releases the lock.

Comment: @jameslarge You are right, but the return statement in `foo` is inside the synchronized block, which I am not sure whill release the lock.

Comment: @texasbruce, The Java Language Spec guarantees that there is no way to exit from a synchronized block without releasing the lock.  Doesn't matter if there is a return statement in the middle of the block.  Doesn't matter if the block throws an exception.  There is no way out without releasing the lock.

Comment: @jameslarge Sure didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @texasbruce `foo()`'s return statement is *not* inside the synchronized block. The block is `{ … }`, and doesn't include anything in `synchronized (…)`. The lock isn't acquired until `{`.

Answer (score 1):

The second example synchronizes on the thing returned from foo, but does not synchronize on anything else, like m. According to the Java Language Spec, when a thread is attempting to enter a synchronized block, the expression in parens after the synchronized keyword is evaluated and the result is the object whose monitor the thread has to acquire.

Synchronizing depends on having shared locks, if your methods are not sharing the same lock then it won't work. If you need the code to acquire the lock on m as well, you can do something like

```
static void bar(Map m, String key) {
    synchronized (m) {
        synchronized (foo (m,key) ) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

because intrinsic locks are re-entrant (acquiring the lock in the outer block doesn't stop foo from acquiring it again).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and more examples!